I need to access values from a MAP datatype in Redshift Spectrum
I have very large (1 billion + records) files in S3, that I am querying via Amazon Redshift using Spectrum.
I have a datatype in Redshift as follows:
map<string,struct<string_value:string,int_value:bigint,float_value:double,double_value:double>>
When I query the data like this:
SELECT 
ep.value.int_value
FROM table a, a.events ep
WHERE ep.key = 'event_id' 

It works, and I get a result back.
However, what I want is to be able to select the value, without needing to add anything in the where clause.
The query below, works for Athena. Is there a similar thing for Redshift?
SELECT
event_params['event_id'].int_value AS event_id
FROM table a


Thanks in advance!
I tried using dot notation in the select, but I get an error.
Update:
SELECT
(SELECT max(ep.value.int_value) from a.events as ep where b.key = 'event_id')
FROM table a

This works, but is this cost efficient? Given the millions of rows I need to do analysis on...

Your first query is “unnesting” the array “events” in the FROM clause - “FROM table a, a.events ep“.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html.  Basically this is mapping all the values of the events array into rows.
It is not clear why you cannot just remove the WHERE clause.  You will likely get some NULL values where events isn’t defined but cleaning that up is straight forward.

Thanks for the reply. My table has billions of rows. Each row has about 12 keys in the events param, so unnesting in the FROM ends up exploding the table to 12 x the size. I'm only interested in 2 of the keys. Any ideas on how I can optimize it?

You can’t use a WHERE clause until you expand it.  This should be fairly fast as it can toss non-matching keys as soon as it is expanded.  Redshift is very good with large amounts of data especially if the data can be filtered serially as this can.  The other way to go is to string match on the JSON equivalent and then expand into a SUPER for unnesting.  I think this being faster is unlikely but you can try.
